# How to empty Char Array and reuse the same in C?

Tags: c, arrays, file

I am trying to read a file. I want to read each line from the file and check if there are any spelling error in that line.

For that I have added condition that data from file will store in buffer until it gets a new line characher `'\n'`. And after getting this line I want to empty the buffer and re insert the values in that.

Code I am using for the same is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define W_COUNT 23800
#define MAX_LEN 100

char *dict[W_COUNT];
char buffer[MAX_LEN];
int num_words;      //No of Words
char *statement[W_COUNT];
char buffer1[MAX_LEN];

void read_dictionary();
void file_read(char *);
void spell_check();
int word_search(char*);

int main(int argc, char*argv[]){
  int i;
  if(argc < 2){
    printf("Expected Filename.\n");
    exit(0);
  }
  read_dictionary();
  file_read(argv[1]);
//  spell_check();
}

void read_dictionary(){
  FILE *fd;
  int i = 0;
  fd = fopen("dictionary", "r");
  while ( fscanf(fd,"%s",buffer) != EOF)
    dict[i++] = strdup(buffer);
  num_words = i;
  fclose(fd);
}

void file_read(char *filename){
  FILE *fd;
  int i = 0;
  char c;
  fd = fopen(filename,"r");
  /*while ( fscanf(fd,"%s",buffer1) != EOF)
  {
    word[i++] = strdup(buffer1);
    printf("File : %s\n", buffer1);
  }*/
  while ( ( c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF )
  {
    buffer1[i++] = tolower(c);
    if ( c == '\n')
    {
      //printf("New Line\n");
      spell_check();
      buffer1[i] = 0;

    }
    //buffer1[i] = 0;
  }
  printf("Statement : %s\n", buffer1);
  fclose(fd);
}

void spell_check(){
  char *str;
  str = strtok(buffer1," .?,!-");
  while( str != NULL){
    if(!word_search(str))
    printf("%s Not found.\n",str);
    str = strtok(0," .?,!-");
  }
}

int word_search(char *word){

  int high, low, mid;
  high = num_words - 1;
  low = 0;
  int found = 0;

  while (found == 0){
    mid = (low + high) / 2;
    if(strcmp(word, dict[mid]) == 0)
    return 1;
    else if(strcmp(word,dict[mid]) < 0)
    high = mid - 1;
    else
    low = mid + 1;
    if ( low > high)
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: you can assign a null character to the starting of the buffer.

Comment: I tried but not working. It only loop through the first line.

Comment: In where you assign the null character in coding?

Comment: spell_check();
buffer1[0] = NULL; I have tried here..

Comment: For each line reading you have to assign the value of i to 0. But you didn't do that. Then you have to to assign the null character to the buffer.

Comment: How about memset the content of the array to \0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while ( ( c = fgetc(fd)) != EOF )
  {
    buffer1[i++] = tolower(c);
    if ( c == '\n')
    {
      //printf("New Line\n");
      spell_check();
      i = 0;
      buffer1[i] = 0;

    }
    //buffer1[i] = 0;
  }
```

For each line reading you have to assign the 0 to the i. After that you have to assign the null to the 0th position in the buffer.
You can try the above code for loop it will work.